# Lebesgue Integral: calculation of limit

Tags: limits, lebesgue-integral

I need to calculate the following limit, using basic Lebesgue integral properties and lemmas:

$$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\underset{}{\int_{(a,\infty)}\frac{n}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}}.$$

Comment: What do you know about the lebesgue integral of a pointwise limit of functions?

Comment: The problem here is when $a\leq0$,  i think i can't get the limit inside the integral.

Comment: Have you tried making the substitution $x = y/n$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1) if $n \ge 1$ is an integer then $0 \le \dfrac{n}{1 + n^2 x^2} \le \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

2) $0 \le \displaystyle \int_{(a,\infty)} \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx \le \int_{(-\infty,\infty)} \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \, dx < \infty$.